# Pump Automatic Pressure Control Electronic Switch

Tags: charge-pump

What is the name of this small part?
[image]

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic for this site, I suggest you remove that element from your question or it is likely to be closed.

Comment: if you can, reverse the actuator magnet. that may fix the problem.

Comment: @laptop2d "Where you can buy..." IS a shopping question, hence my suggestion to remove that element from it.

Comment: I see that now, I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [Reed Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_switch) - a pair of contacts that open or close in the presence of a magnetic field.

You'll need to select one that is capable of handling the current requirements for your circuit, which is impossible to determine without knowing more about its function.

You'll also need to determine whether the contacts should be normally open or closed, i.e. whether the magnetic field opens or closes the switch.

Answer (score 0):

As Finbarr says it is a reed switch.
Try to find out what happened to that part. If is just mechanically broken that is one thing.  But if it is electrically broken, the most likely cause was a short circuit. Make sure the short is no longer present before you use the new one.

Comment: Reed switch, not reed relay...

Comment: Sorry: corrected!